# Delete file after upload to ftp in Apache Camel

Tags: java, ftp, upload, apache-camel

Is there a simple way to delete a file after a successfully uploading? I'm using Camel v2.17.0. 
My route looks like this:

```
from("direct:upload-content").to(
            "ftp://{{upload.user}}@{{upload.host}}:{{upload.port}}{{upload.dir}}?password={{upload.pass}}&doneFileName=done.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the options delete=true for deleting the file after successful transfer or move=.done for moving it to a different folder